# Display an empty listview which gets loaded in a while

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have two fragments. Clicking in left fragment will populate the listview in right fragment, but before clicking I want to display some text, a textview may be. Now how do I display something at the time of loading and change it to listview when an item is clicked in left fragment. Left one is extending ListFragment and right one is extending Fragment.

I have a textview defined in details.xml which is getting loaded successfully at the time of startup. Now I want to display a listview that receives an array from left fragment.

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.details, container, false);

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you to use a `emptyView` for your `listview` when you init it.

```
// init
mTextViewLoad.setText("Loading");
mListView.setEmptyView(mTextViewLoad);
```

This is really useful because your `textview` will automatically be hidden / shown. Just change the text to "empty" whan your loading is finished.

Hope this will help you.